# regular expression question

Tags: php, regex

I have a query like this

```
SELECT a, (SELECT b FROM w), (SELECT c FROM x) FROM y WHERE a IN (SELECT d FROM z)
```

and I want to convert it to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM y WHERE a IN (SELECT d FROM z)
```

in php. this is a sample and quires are different than this.

Actually the regex must only replace everything between first SELECT and FROM pair with COUNT(*) but do not touch SELECT after that. and it also must consider that there are some other SELECT FROM pair inside the first pair and replace them too.

I use this now

```
preg_replace('/SELECT (.*?) FROM/', 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM', $sql, 1)
```

but it don't detect the SELECT inside the first SELECT * FROM

Comment: That sounds like a very strange task. You may want to think about why you are trying to do that, and if there is a better solution to the higher-level problem

Comment: What is the actual pattern? Because for this you could just do: `str_replace('SELECT f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM t2) FROM t1 WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f4 FROM t)', 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f4 FROM t)')`

Comment: if that's only that you can use str_replace

Comment: I don't think you need regex for that. You could just replace everything before `FROM` with `SELECT COUNT(*)`, using `substr_replace`.

Comment: f1, f2 are samples. I have different queries that typically is like this and I want to get the count of them.

Comment: @Ali are you writing a paginator? Specifying that should yield much better responses.

Comment: yes, it's for paginator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace` seems like overkill here. Why don't you use `str_replace` or better, `str_ireplace`?

```
$sql = 'SELECT f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM t2) FROM t1 WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f4 FROM t)';
$fixed_sql = str_ireplace('f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM t2)', 'COUNT(*)', $sql);
```

If the query is not the same always, you can:

```
$sql = 'SELECT f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM t2) FROM t1 WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f4 FROM t)';
$fixed_sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' . substr($sql, strpos($sql, ' FROM');
```

(Untested, but the concept is the same).

Comment: the query is not always like this :( it's a sample

Comment: Then, you want to replace the column list with a COUNT(*) right?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you use regex to replace everything between a `SELECT` and a `FROM` with `COUNT(*)`. Using a straightforward regex pattern, you can do that in 2 different ways:

1. greedily match everything between `SELECT` and `FROM`
2. lazily match everything between `SELECT` and `FROM`

Let's take your example input:

```
SELECT f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM t2) FROM t1 WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f4 FROM t)
```

option `1` would match the following:

```
SELECT f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM t2) FROM t1 WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f4 FROM
```

*(the first `SELECT` and the last `FROM`)*

and option `2` would match the following:

```
SELECT f1, f2, (SELECT f3 FROM
```

*(the first `SELECT` and the first `FROM`)*

Replacing either pattern with something else would break your SQL. Of course there are more "clever" ways to create a pattern to account for this particular SQL input, but I am pretty sure that for every "smart" regex, I (or someone else) will easily find an SQL script that would get "broken" by it.

You might think to use a recursive pattern, but they're a pain to write and maintain, and they too can break SQL code like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE x='FOO WHERE BAR' ...
```

*(a literal string containing keywords)*

or

```
SELECT ... WHERE ...     -- FOO WHERE BAR
```

*(a comment containing keywords)*

So, my answer to you is: don't use regex for this. Use some sort of [SQL parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/) instead.

Comment: Edited to replace "reluctantly" with "lazily", which seems a better/more common term for this. Feel free to roll back if you prefer the other way. Otherwise, spot on.

Comment: @Justin, no, it's fine like this. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out myself: {SELECT ((?:(?:(?!SELECT|FROM).)++|SELECT(?1)FROM)*) FROM}six

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$sql = preg_replace("/^.*( FROM t1)/", "SELECT COUNT(*)$1", $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the particular pattern you gave:

`SELECT ... (...) FROM ...`

The following works:

```
$sql = preg_replace('/^SELECT .*\(.*\) (FROM.*)$/', 'SELECT COUNT(*) $1', $sql);
```

But as @Bart pointed out, any deviation from this pattern will break your SQL.